# thieves guild guests need help?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to complete a major Thieves' Guild quest, which requires me to gain a certain level of influence in each area.  This appears to be done by accepting and completing minor quests, or "jobs", from the other Thieves' Guild members.  I've been able to achieve these objectives for all areas except Markarth.  In all this time though, I've only gotten one job in Markarth.

Is there something else I should be doing to gain influence there, or some way to steer the available jobs to Markarth, so that I can complete this quest?

Comment: More details please.

Comment: While I agree this question is a bit short on details, compared to what would generally be considered a "good question", I think it's fairly easy to surmise what is being asked.  In fact, I really can't see what more detail is actually needed?  @Tarkenfire seems to have addressed it well.

Comment: Did a little overhaul on the question.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean how do you get the quest for Markarth because all of the mini-quests are in cities not Markarth?

In that case, simply take, then give up on missions till you get a Markarth one. For better results, once you get a mission for Markarth from one of the two mission givers, save, then repeat the cycle of taking, then gibing up on missions till you get a second Markarth one.

As for what kind of missions will be fastest, those are subjective, but I usually find heist (Vex) and numbers (Devlin) fast due to how simple they are. Sweep (Vex) and Bedlam(Devlin) are the most complex, and by extension, longest of the radiant quests the two offer.

Comment: If I recall correctly, wasn't Markarth one of the rarer cities to get quests for?

Comment: @Iszi yea, for most of the radiant quests, Markarth only has 3-4 options compared to 5-6 for some other cities so there's less probability of getting one of them.